# Does the New Republic still exist at the end of the movie?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

It wasn't clear to me if the New Republic still exists at the end of
*The Force Awakens*?

Comment: To be honest, the destruction of those planets felt like such an incidental afterthought in the plot that I wouldn't be surprised if they just carry on like it didn't happen

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it conflicts with our [future works policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, for now.

1. According to *[The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)* (Page 8: Peace Interrupted + Galaxy map), it seems to still exists, alongside First Order and the Resistance.
2. Republic consists of hundreds of worlds, and a set of laws.

   An equivalent situation would be someone blowing up entire Washington, DC. USA would still exist, even though the capital and the elected government body are gone, though clearly in a weakened state and in turmoil.
3. However, it may not exist for long:

   Obviously, the Senate of the New Republic and its whole government AND most of its fleet got

   > Blown up when Starkiller Base destroyed Hosnian Prime where it was located at that time.

   Which means that the Resistance might need to re-merge with it in the future, considering that we learn that even before Hosnian Prime being destroyed, the Republic wasn't doing all that well (from Leia, not Snoke):

   > There was no one else she could rely on. No one like her brother. No one else at all, now that the New Republic stood on the verge of implosion, of destruction, of complete collapse.
   >   ...
   >   Times were desperate. The ruthless First Order was on the march, threatening to overwhelm the shaky framework of the weak, increasingly vulnerable, and still-developing New Republic.
   >   *(TFA novelization by Alan Dean Foster)*

Answer (score 4):

**Probably.**

Just like the Empire didn't totally disappear with the loss of its leader during the second battle of the Death Star, it is very likely that the Republic still stands, albeit in a reduced capacity, at the end of the movie.

The Republic is the governing body for most of the Star Wars Galaxy, and not just the few planets we see during the movie. As a real world comparison, it would be similar to assuming that the sudden destruction of the White House would dissolve the entirety of the United States. Just like it didn't work out for the British in 1814, I'm pretty sure the Republic has other officials throughout the Galaxy that can take over the administration during these troubled times.

These are only speculations, however, and perhaps the novelization or other references yet to be published at this time will shed more light on the matter. Otherwise, we'll have to wait for the opening crawl to Episode VIII...

Comment: Taiwan is another example of a government adapting and lasting well after an overthrow.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is still around! If you blew up DC would the USA be gone.No! The fleet wouldn't also be gone as well. Of course the book says most of the fleet was destroyed. I honestly think it couldn't be that much. They probably have half the fleet distributed around their space. I mean the US wouldn't put all it's troops in DC right?

Comment: Reminds me of the TV show "Designated Survivor" about if the cabinet is blown up they have one senator stay in a bunker. So, I assume something similar happens in the Republic.

Comment: @JCtitanic-this sounds like an opinion can you site any canon references?